# Setting a BackGround image in an Applet

Tags: java, swing

Hello everyone i have this Image that i want it to appear as my background and my other information to be on top of it i want it to fill the entire JApplet, can anyone give me the method... please.

I dont know if i should include a `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`

the add the background? am new in Java help me.

```
backGround = getImage(getCodeBase(), "download.jpg");
        BackGroundPanel background = new BackGroundPanel();
        background.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        background.setBackGroundImage(backGround);
```

I have imported my jpg to my src java but cant load.

Comment: Also take a look at [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html)

Comment: Why is it marked duplicate? I tried those solutions and couldnt work? :(

Comment: It's the same process, create a custom component, extending from `JPanel`, override it's `paintComponent` method and paint your image within it.  Apply this component as the `JApplet`'s `contentPane` and initialise the UI as you normally would. The fact that you're using applet doesn't actually change how it's done.  I suspect that you're not loading the image correctly, hence the reason I also added the link to [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html), as you state the image is your `src` directory, which means it you can't use `getImage`

Comment: hey @MadProgrammer forgive me for asking but where is this location? getCodeBase(), and can i save my picture there? am reading the link too. I have been learning Java on my own

Comment: Try using ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/path/to/image/download.jpg")). With the images stored in the src directory, the image is like embedded in the resulting jar and not stored on the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a quick testapplet I wrote to test this, and it seems to work (should work with any Java version as well). It draws the background, and places a label (so any Component) on top of it.

**Code:**

```
import java.applet.Applet;
import java.awt.*;
import java.net.*;
public class BGTest extends Applet
{
    Label testLabel;
    Image bgImage = null; 

    public void init()
    {
        try 
        { 
            MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker (this);
            bgImage = getImage
            (new URL("download.jpg")); 
            tracker.addImage(bgImage, 0);
        } catch (Exception e) { System.out.println(e.toString());}      
        testLabel=new Label("Testing");
        add(testLabel);     
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {   
        super.paint(g);
        g.drawImage(bgImage,0,0,this); 
    }
}
```

Comment: does the size matter? it doesnt work i have my image in my src in java.

Comment: You should be calling super.paint ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer oops i forgot to add it. Thanks ;)

Comment: I also just realised that the OP is using a `JApplet` (Swing), but you've presented a AWT solution...

Comment: This is not working :( so frustrating.